# scala Slider throws casting exception

Tags: swing, scala

I create an Slider object:

```
    val slider = new Slider{
        min = 0
        max = 30
        labels = Map(0 -> new Label("Nula"),15-> new Label("Pul"),30-> new Label("Max"))
        paintLabels = true
    }
```

when I run this, an exception is thrown:
scala.swing.Label cannot be cast to java.awt.Component
but why?
When i browse the docs, the excpected type for labels is a Map[Int,Label].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, which was corrected for Scala 2.8 about 8 months ago.